# Reading a file into a structure array and using isupper

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct

The goal of the program is the read a textile that contains various animal names (some fully uppercase some fully lowercase) put this info into a struct array (in this case struct animal allAnimals[6]) then print out the animals name, id and whether or not it is upper or lowercase using the structure defined (struct animal).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){


FILE *fptr;
  
  fptr = fopen("all_animals.txt", "r");
  if (fptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error! File cannot be opened");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<6;i++){
  fscanf(fptr, "%s",allAnimals[i].name);
    }

    return(0);
}

int isUppercaseAnimal(char animal[50]){
  for(int j=0; j< strlen(animal); j++){
   if(isupper(animal[j])){
            return(1);
        }else{
            return(0);
             }//else
         }//j
}//isUpperCase


struct animal allAnimals[6];
struct animal{

char name[50];
int animal_Id;
int isUpperCase;

};

int print(char s[50], int n, int c){

if(c == 1) printf("ID: %d\n Name: %s\n This animals is written in all capitals\n",n,s);
if(c == 0) printf("ID: %d\n Name: %s\n This animals is written in all lowercase\n",n,s);

return(0);
}
```

It is currently giving me these errors [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOUmp.png) What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You did not define or declare `allAnimals[]` before its first use.

Comment: You `return(1)` from `isUppercaseAnimal` before checking every character. The complier hint is to place that after the loop completes.

Comment: Because your function doesn't loop through the for-loop and basically doesn't return anything so the compiler issues a warning that the control reaches the end of a non-void function which means you don't return anything. (no return encountered) The other error is related to the compiler not knowing the size of your struct, so you need to define it up in your main and the size of the array of the struct to help the compiler to arrange space for it.

Comment: Note that `isupper` only works with unibyte characters; calling it with a parameter that is not within the range of `UCHAR_MAX` or equal to `EOF` is undefined behavior. If you would like to support multibyte characters, you'll be better off using the wide character interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

First declare your `animal` struct, then your `allAnimals` array, than start with the `main` function. The order is important, because your `fscanf` can't see ahead the definition of the `animal` struct. It must be defined before it's used.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

struct animal{

char name[50];
int animal_Id;
int isUpperCase;

};
struct animal allAnimals[6];


int main(){


FILE *fptr;

  fptr = fopen("all_animals.txt", "r");
  if (fptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error! File cannot be opened");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<6;i++){
  fscanf(fptr, "%s",allAnimals[i].name);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

etc. etc.